# Fingers model file is missing Verifinger

Tags: winforms, fingerprint

I wanted to use Verifinger (https://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html) in my forms APP. I have integrated the changes properly. Everything works properly except after I placed my finger on the device it started showing the picture and then when it considers the picture is OK the it throws this error **Fingers model file is missing**.

After integrating the trail version in my forms app I started seeing this.

FYI: In the trail version the exe they provided to test works fine without any error. Error happens only with my application. I even tried to load whole forms in the trail package in my application.

I just need to understand where to start. As I couldn't find this error in their documentation

MyForms APP: .net 4.8 with 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, copy the files from Lib\Win64_x64. If you are performing an extract operation, also copy all the database files with the .ndf extension. This should be enough for it to work properly. In linux the process is the same, but you need copy the .so files and the database files.